# Bios Beeps and no Start Up

Tags: bios

My computer started having problems during start up. Now it has gotten worse because when I press the power button, nothing starts up, even the fan and all I hear is four long beeps in five intervals. I have tried using a different power suppy but it did no good, I still got the beeps. I have also disassembled everything and asssemled them back and also it did no good. What could be the problem and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Check your motherboard manual to determine what the beeps mean.  Without specific information about the motherboard we cannot help

Comment: Usually this indicates some sort of hardware failure, usually either the RAM or the CPU, but it could really be any component on the motherboard. As @Ramhound has indicated the exact error codes should be in the motherboard manual.

Comment: Thanks Ramhound, the motherboard is for an HP Compaq DC 7800 series. Does that help?

Comment: @HarrisPunkiMwangi - Check the HP website for information about the Bios Beep Codes.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Troubleshooting manual](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.BINARYPORTLET/public/kb/docDisplay/resource.process/?spf_p.tpst=kbDocDisplay_ws_BI&spf_p.rid_kbDocDisplay=docDisplayResURL&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&spf_p.rst_kbDocDisplay=wsrp-resourceState%3DdocId%253Demr_na-c01162207-8%257CdocLocale%253Den_CA&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) for your HP model (from HP.com):

**Activity:**

Red Power LED flashes four times, once every second, followed by a two second pause. Beeps stop after fifth iteration but LEDs continue until problem is solved.

**Beeps:**

4

**Possible Cause:**

Power failure (power supply is overloaded).

*OR*

The incorrect external power supply adapter is being used on the USDT.

**Recommended Action:**

1. Open the hood and ensure the 4 or 6-wire power supply cable is seated into the connector on the system board.
2. Check if a device is causing the problem by removing ALL attached devices (such as hard, diskette, or optical drives, and expansion cards). Power on the system. If the system enters the POST, then power off and replace one device at a time and repeat
   this procedure until failure occurs. Replace the device that is causing the failure.
   Continue adding devices one at a time to ensure all devices are functioning properly.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. Well mine is a bit different, the power LED does not blink at intervals, it only blinks when I press the power button then it goes off then the four beeps start. What is USDT?

Comment: There's a few different chassis variations for the at model, so some of them may not have the diag. LED system hooked up.  Regardless, according to the troubleshooting (and experience) it looks to be a power issue, try a new power supply. I fit doesn't help, come back and edit your question, updating it to reflect what you tried and what the results were.

Comment: Doesn't your computer have Internet access to a search engine?   USDT = Ultra Slim DeskTop.  Please do your part in investigating your issues, this is SuperUser.com, not "Tell me how to fix my computer based on vague information and answer all my questions along the way".com. ;)

Answer (score 0):

From the sounds of it, there might be a problem with your CPU, but you might want to include a bit more detail if possible.  The beeps that you are hearing are commonly referred to as [Beep Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beep_code), which are typically heard during POST.

Here are a few links that you might find useful: [Cheat sheet 1](http://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm), [Cheat Sheet 2](http://www.technick.net/public/code/cp_dpage.php?aiocp_dp=guide_beep_codes)

From the guides linked above:

> Beeps: **5**
>
> Description: **The CPU has generated an undetectable error**

It might be a good idea to disassemble your computer and *carefully* remove the CPU heat sink and CPU itself.  Examine the CPU thoroughly to ensure that no pins have been bent, or that any thermal paste as leaked onto the CPU connectors on your motherboard.

If you can't see anything visibly wrong, I would *highly* suggest following @Ramhound's advice and refer to your user manual for further instructions.

Comment: The OP said "4 long beeps in 5 intervals", not "5 beeps" :)